# Multiple PHP based server blocks in nginx - 404 Error

Tags: php, nginx, centos7

I am pretty new in Nginx and I have a problem with it. I have two wordpress websites and I want to start them with Nginx on a Centos Linux. What I have done is:

1. creating sites-available and sites-enabled in the /etc/nginx/
2. Put my website configuration files (.conf) into sites-available
3. I created symbolic links for them using `ln -s`

My configuration files are as follow:
**nginx.conf**

```
http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
  #   include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf
    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index        index.html;
        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
}
```

**mydomain1.com.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain1.com www.mydomain1.com;
    location / {
        root /var/www/html/;
        index index.php;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

**mydomain2.com.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain2.com www.mydomain2.com;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        root /var/www/aramis;
        index index.php;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

**/etc/php-fm.d/www.conf**

```
[www]
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
listen.owner = nobody
listen.group = nobody
;listen.mode = 0660
user = nginx
group = nginx
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 35
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_value[session.save_handler] = files
php_value[session.save_path] = /var/lib/php/session
```

I also tried to find php-fpm.sock but I was not successful.
What I get when try to see my websites from browser is **404 Error.**

Comment: You'd be better off asking on [sf]. But don't crosspost.

Comment: What do the NGINX access logs have?

Comment: It just shows my tries to see my websites

Answer (score 1):

You have no `root` directive for your PHP location block. If it is the same root for all files (both static and dynamic) then move the `root` directive to the `server` block and allow the same value to be inherited by both `location` blocks.

```
server {
    ...
    root /var/www/aramis;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        ...
    }
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Your need resolve the redundance

**mydomain1.com.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html/; # Set as global
    server_name mydomain1.com www.mydomain1.com;
    index index.php # Set index as global
    location / {
        # index index.php; #Remove this line
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

**myworkingfile.conf**

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name  crm.coderic.net;
    root /var/www/atrk/crm.atrk.com.co/public;
    index index.php;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```